# Python:-Issue regarding downloading the file from the url

Tags: python

I am unable to download a file from the website www.nse.com...it shows me the following message when I try to run the code

**ERROR:-**
    
    Access Denied

## Access Denied

```
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;nseindia&#46;com&#47;content&#47;historical&#47;EQUITIES&#47;2016&#47;JUN&#47;cm13JUN2016bhav&#46;csv&#46;zip" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;4ef0ef75&#46;1465880369&#46;ab8f79e
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Not Downloaded

And my code is this :

**CODE**

```
import urllib2

urlOfFileName="http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2016/JUN/cm13JUN2016bhav.csv.zip"

localZipFilePath="C:\Users\sai\Desktop\cm13JUN2016bhav.csv.zip"

hdr ={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36'}

webRequest=urllib2.Request(urlOfFileName,headers=hdr)

try:
    page=urllib2.urlopen(webRequest)
    content=page.read()
    output=open(localZipFilePath,"wb")
    output.write(bytearray(content))
    output.close()

except urllib2.HTTPError,e:
    print e.fp.read()
    print "Not Downloaded"
```

I have used the User_Agent Header also..I am not able to understand the problem.Please help me out in this.

Comment: Thats because you simply don't have access to the site. Maybe it requires some sort of authorization. I can't even access the site from Chrome.

Comment: I managed to work around this, but in the process, it became clear that the owner of the website is specifically trying to prevent programmatic access to the file. I've decided not to share my solution.

Comment: Yeah. I'm pretty sure there are means to get historic stock exchange data legally

Comment: But I am able to download the file directly from the website. This is the url of the site.   https://www.nseindia.com/..   and actually I am taking a course on python programming.So the instructor taught me this code.The code works fine for her.She is able to download the file.

Comment: and this is the url of the file which she has downloaded                                     http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2016/JUN/cm13JUN2016bhav.csv.zip

Comment: ok.. I'm able to download it programatically too. I wonder why you're getting an access denied error

Comment: @smarx it doesn't seem like its trying to block bot downloads. I'm able to download the file without any problems

Comment: yeah thats my problem :(...I have also included User agent header also which includes my browser information..But I am still getting the error.Can you please help me out

Comment: I'm not familiar with python 2.x. I used the `urlretrieve` function from the `urllib.request` module in python 3.5. I used the same header as you did and was able to download it successfully

Comment: And I am working on ipython notebook

Comment: @SvbZ3r0 As I said, in finding my workaround, it became pretty clear that programmatic downloads were being specifically denied.

Comment: Make sure your header is complete. Not sure if it makes a diff. Mine is: HDR = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.47 Safari/537.36",'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Charset': 'Windows-1252,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5','Connection': 'keep-alive'}

Comment: @smarx um.. I **CAN** download the file without any problems using `urlretrieve`. I didn't hit any `access denied` or `forbidden` error.

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom Thank you it works fine now.I am able to download the file..So do we have to specify the header completely everytime?Since websites that give your browser user agent are not giving completely like you did?If possible,please tell me a solution for finding this complete header.

Comment: @SvbZ3r0 I am not getting the error if I include the entire header as  mentioned.

Comment: @SaiSankalp But I used the same header you did and didn't face any problems. Something's fishy

Comment: @SvbZ3r0 The fact that their protection isn't very *good* isn't relevant. :-) All I'm pointing out is (what I perceive as) a clear intent on their part.

Comment: @SvbZ3r0 yeah actually I am newbie to python and I have referred to some sites.They are not even giving the full header but the code is working fine for them.I dont understand.Do you think in python 2.x,we need to give the full header?

Comment: @smarx I'm sure this is a question that requires a long answer, but to an average user, how would you know a file is restricted when you're downloading it? If I was the one trying to download this file, this question wouldn't have popped up in SO and I wouldn't have known I wasn't supposed to download it. Is there a way to check before downloading? Or should I ask this as a separate question in SO?

Comment: I honestly, have no idea @SaiSankalp

Comment: @SaiSankalp Either going to chrome://version or http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/. for the rest I looked up on another thread on stack